# If $(V,k)$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then the space of all linear transformations on $V$ is finite dim and find its dim?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, numerical-linear-algebra

My issue with this is the only way I know how to prove it is to set $\dim V=n$, but then that wouldn't make sense because the second part is finding the $\dim$. 
What I was thinking is using the rank-nullity theorem $$\rm rank(A)+N(A)=n \ \text{or} \ \dim(\rm Im(A))+\dim(\ker(A))=\dim V$$ Any suggestions on how to prove that if $(V,K)$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then the space of all linear transformations on $V$ is finite dimensional and to find its dimension?

Comment: Hint: Fising a basis, every linear transformation are $n\times n$ matrices. What is the dimension of the space of all such matrices?

Comment: @ Tiffany:  did you mean to say the set of linear transformations is *finite dimensuonal*, or actually *finite*?

Comment: I am trying to prove that the linear transformation L(V,V)={f:v->v} is finite dimensional Given that f is linear @Robert Lewis

Comment: There is no way to use rank-nullity here. That theorem is about individual linear transformations, while here you are looking at the space of _all_ linear operators; there is no linear transformation of _that_ space in the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to show that, given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$, the space $S$ of linear transformations $T: V \to V$ is finite dimensional.

Here's a suggestion for how to proceed: First, show that $S$ is a vector space (if you haven't already). You can do this straight from the definition. (Show that if $T, U \in S$ and $\alpha, \beta \in F$ then $\alpha T + \beta U \in S$, which is to say that $(\alpha T + \beta U)(v) = \alpha T(v) + \beta U(v)$ is a linear transformation.)

Let $n = \dim V \in \mathbb{N}$. Fixing a basis allows us to identify $V$ with $F^n$ and $S$ with the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$. If you think about it, there should be a clear choice for a basis of this space $S$ over $F$ now.

If you're not seeing it, imagine taking the rows of an $n\times n$ matrix and laying them out in a line. Note you can do this for any $n\times n$ matrix, and so this allows you to think of $S$ as being essentially the same vector space as $F^{n^2}$. You now have an element of $F^{n^2}$. What's a basis for $F^{n^2}$? Relate this back to a basis for $S$. What's the order of the basis you found? It should be a function of $n$.

Ah. I just saw your edit. Note you're trying to find the dimension of $\dim S$, and so it's perfectly fine to set $\dim V = n$. In fact, you should expect that $\dim S$ is going to be a function of $\dim V$, and so this is the natural thing to do.

Comment: So can I say, Let dim V = n By the rank-nullity theorem rank(f) + null(f) = dim V = n, where rank f = dim(Im(f)) and null(f) = dim(Ker(f)) This implies rank f less that or equal to n and null(f) less that or equal to n. Then since rank f, null f are real numbers, we know that the vectors in the spans of the Image and Kernel of f are finite and so any linear transformation on f is finite dimensional

Comment: @Tiffany: Do you know that the space of linear transformation $\{T: V\to V\}$ is a vector space?

Comment: The problem is with the "so" in "... and so any linear transformation on f is finite dimensional". It isn't clear to me from your argument how "the dimensions of the image and kernel of a given $T:V \to V$ are finite" implies "the dimension of the set $S$ of all linear transformations $T$ is finite".

Comment: oh, hmm. Well yes {F: v-> v} is a vector space. I was thinking if dim ker f + dim Im f = n, some finite number then dim ker f + dim Im f are also finite numbers, but now that I am thinking about it Im trying to prove that f:v->v is finite and thus my answer wouldnt make sense. Well now, I am clueless