# Linear Algebra Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Let  $L(U,V)$ = $\{T:U\rightarrow V\ :\ T\ \text{linear}\},$ and dim $(U)=n$, dim $(V)=m$. Then show that $$
\dim L(U,V) = mn.
$$
I don't know how to begin and I already searched the internet to find something, but  could not. Please if anybody could help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551031/if-v-k-is-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-then-the-space-of-all-linear-tr

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that linear mappings are in one-to-one correspondence with matrices? That helps a lot here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis of $U$ and $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ a basis of $V$.

Set $T_{ij}:U\to V$ to be the linear transformation such that
$$
T_{ij}(c_1e_1+\cdots+c_ne_n)=c_if_j.
$$
Then $T_{ij}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, $j=1,\ldots,m$ form a basis of $L(U,V)$.